# Sending money from India to US - What are the PayPal charges that apply

Tags: india, international-transfer, paypal

I have a PayPal account in India. And due to our banking regulations we cannot use PayPal for personal payments. I need to send some money over to a PayPal account in the US, and I have been asked to mark it as 'friends and family'.

Now, when I go to the 'send Payment' page, I don't see an option to mark it as 'friends and family'. All I see is: 'Sending payments for purchases is free for you. The seller pays the fees.'

My question is, if I send a payment of 10 USD, will the receiver in US receive the 10 USD, or a lesser amount after adjusting the PayPal charges? Another problem is that they don't say anything about the exact amount that the seller will see.

Comment: Just send USD$11. There is no way that Merchant Fee + Cross Border Fee + Currency Exchange Fee + Visa Fee + Every Fee could exceed $1 for a payment of $10.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal charges a 2.5% currency conversion fee to exchange funds from one currency to another. That means, the receiver would receive $ 9.75. [Read More](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Tips-from-Moderators/Currency-Conversion-Rates/td-p/456085)